# Converting a dictionary value in to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
'state_license': {u'License ': u'29393, 25633', 
                  u'Expiration': u'08-01-2012, 04-02-2012', 
                  u'Trade': u'Registered Contractor, Plumber'}
```

How can I convert `'29393, 25633'` into a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> state_license = {u'License ': u'29393, 25633',
...                  u'Expiration': u'08-01-2012, 04-02-2012',
...                  u'Trade': u'Registered Contractor, Plumber'}
>>> {key: value.split(", ") for key, value in state_license.items()}
{u'License ': [u'29393', u'25633'], 
 u'Expiration': [u'08-01-2012', u'04-02-2012'], 
 u'Trade': [u'Registered Contractor', u'Plumber']}
```

Comment: @RikPoggi: Thanks for fixing the typo!

Answer (score 3):

With [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> '29393, 25633'.split(', ')
['29393', '25633']
```

It's not clear, but you seem to have a double nested dictionary, something like:

```
d = {'state_license': {'License ': '29393, 25633', 
                       'Expiration': '08-01-2012, 04-02-2012', 
                       'Trade': 'Registered Contractor, Plumber'}}
```

To convert:

```
nested = d['state_license']
for k,v in nested.iteritems():
    nested[k] = v.split(', ')

"""
{'state_license': {'License ': ['29393', '25633'], 
                    'Expiration': ['08-01-2012', '04-02-2012'], 
                    'Trade': ['Registered Contractor', 'Plumber']}}
"""
```

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote? This is the exact answer to the OP's actual question.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah that was strange... I tried to improve it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`split` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for this:

```
>>> u'29393, 25633'.split()
[u'29393,', u'25633']
```

If you have your bigger dictionary in `info` and you want to convert the value in-place, then do

```
info['state_license']['License'] = info['state_license']['License'].split()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary that has the key `'state_license'` is called `d`:

```
[d.__setitem__(k,v.split(", ")) for k,v in d['state_license'].items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the eval() translates the code to generate Python byte code and then executes it in the Python Virtual Machine which is way slower than regular str.split function:

```
help(str.split)
```

in fact, I'd split with ',' instead of ', ' and then strip each item, e.g. (Python3.x dictionary comprehension):

```
{k: [x.strip() for x in v.split(',')] for k, v in dictionary['state_license'].items()}
```

Answer (score -2):

Now. If you want to be a dare-devil (don't!) you can do this:

```
>>> eval('[' + u'29393, 25633' + ']')
[29393, 25633]
```

But... that depends on you knowing what is in that list. It will also break down for other elements:

```
>>> eval('[' + u'08-01-2012, 04-02-2012' + ']')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    [08-01-2012, 04-02-2012]
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

So, stick to the `str.split()` method ;)